# Website not accessible when user doesn't have admin rights

Tags: iis-7, tomcat

I have two websites hosted on a computer with Windows 7. One is hosted on IIS 7 and the other is hosted on Apache Tomcat 7. These websites are accessible from other machines on the network. If I lose my admin rights, they become inaccessible and are accessible only from localhost. What could be the issue behind it?

Comment: Can you give more information about your setup? The OS on your server, for example.

Comment: the computer runs windows 7, the IIS version is 7 and the tomcat version is 7. Added it to the question. Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because Windows 7 isn't a server operating system and is therefore outside of our scope.

Answer (score 3):

Windows 7 is not a server operating system. All bets are off when you use a desktop OS to run services. You are highly advised to use Windows Server or a Linux distribution instead. Unfortunately debugging service problems on Windows 7 or any other desktop-oriented operating system is entirely pointless, as it will be unstable (as you can see), unsupported by all vendors, and difficult if not impossible to find community help.

Comment: Not to mention there's a kernel-level restriction on the number of inbound connections to Windows 7, to something 20.